# How can i use variable in django while accessing models

Tags: python, django

I have this code

`keys = {'speed','temp'}`

I have the variables like

`object.subobj.speed` and `object.subobj.temp`

how can i loop

```
for key in keys
    print object.subobj.key
```

Comment: Actually your code should cause a syntax error, the comma should be replaced by a colon

Comment: which error , its working fine

Comment: I should have been specific, its valid only for python 2.7+

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in keys:
    print getattr(obj.subobj, key)
```